# Building a simple Javascript and HTML server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database, arduino

I am trying to build a simple server to communicate with Arduino and store information recieved from the Arduino. I've established the Arduino server connection using Node.js and Node-serialport, my current code is [here](https://gist.github.com/2945632).

I want to be able to store objects I create in javascript to a sort of database. I've looked around and most of them seem to complex for my needs, as this server will only be running locally. I've seen MongoDB and of course MySQL, but I'd like to use something simpler, like JSON? Any help is a appreciated.

Comment: @Bob Davies is right and, from an Arduino perspective, this would be a beautiful setup. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Apache CouchDB when working with NodeJs and requiring JSON document-modelled data store. It's simple to use, quick to access, and has good support in modules for Node.